# RXJava with Retrofit2 I can't retrieve the server response, nor a simple Log.d

Tags: android, functional-programming, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I see from the debug that the array is retrieved, but if I put in onNext a Log.d with the first position of the array, I do not retrieve the Log in the console, and I do not know if I am calling the first position of the array in a correct way

> Log.d("IVO", "onNext" + stackOverflowQuestions.items.get(0).title.toString());

this is the Main

```
package com.vogella.android.retrofitstackoverflow;

import (..)


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
//original https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=android&site=stackoverflow

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    ArrayAdapter<Question> arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new ArrayList<Question>());
    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setProgressBarVisibility(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
    StackOverflowAPI stackOverflowAPI = retrofit.create(StackOverflowAPI.class);


    //the real call to the server
    //Call<StackOverflowQuestions> call = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions("android");


    Observable<StackOverflowQuestions> observable = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions("android");

    observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<StackOverflowQuestions>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("IVO", "completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(StackOverflowQuestions stackOverflowQuestions) {

                    Log.d("IVO", "onNext" + stackOverflowQuestions.items.get(0).title.toString());
                    Log.d("IVO", "onNext" );
//                        ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Question>) getListAdapter();
//                        adapter.clear();
//                        adapter.addAll(response.body().items);
                }
            });





    return true;
}
```

}

this is StackOverflowQuestions

```
package com.vogella.android.retrofitstackoverflow;

import java.util.List;

public class StackOverflowQuestions {
    List<Question> items;
}
```

this is Question

```
package com.vogella.android.retrofitstackoverflow;

// This is used to map the JSON keys to the object by GSON
public class Question {

    String title;
    String link;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return(title);
    }
}
```

EDIT
StackOverflowAPI as requested:

```
package com.vogella.android.retrofitstackoverflow;

import android.util.Log;

import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import retrofit2.Call;
import rx.Observable;

public interface StackOverflowAPI {
    @GET("/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow")
    //Call<StackOverflowQuestions> loadQuestions(@Query("tagged") String tags);
    Observable<StackOverflowQuestions>  loadQuestions(@Query("tagged") String tags);



}
```

Comment: well yes, you are right, but it is because i tried with the second as well to see if there was an issue with the first one, and then i forget to put it back. Now i edit the post. Still the problem exist anyway

Comment: I suggest you do `e.printStackTrace()` in the `onError` to see if an error occurs. Also, please show us the `StackOverflowAPI` interface to see if there's anything wrong there.

Comment: post Edit with added interface StackOverflowAPI. No error occur. doublechecked with breakpoint and inserting system.out.println(e.getStackTrace));

Comment: Do you still get the onCompleted log entry?  Also, try `Log.d("IVO", "onNext" + stackOverflowQuestions.items.size());`

Comment: @TassosBassoukos. I do not get nothing onCompleted. I tried yesterday <Log.d("IVO", "completed");>  but what you suggest is not possible because OnCompleted() does not have stackOverflowQuestions to pass as parameter, differently by <public void onNext(StackOverflowQuestions stackOverflowQuestions) >

Comment: I almost get it, basically my Subscriber is inside onOptionsItemsMenu, while on the original retrofit 2 implementation was inside onResponse, class that i got rid of... in fact I even cancelled the implements interface

Comment: Try logging the size on the onNext - it might be that you get 0 elements back, or even a null list.

Comment: Unclear question. If you do get array, you do get response from the server and it has nothing to do with logging. What is your question?

Comment: I just found the solution I am going to reply. Thank you Artem to reconsider it again.  In Retrofit2 you get the response in onResponse method.My question was related to RXJava if I can get the response simply in the onNext of the observable and now is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution
 putting this code in onOptionsItemSelected, that is basically where i fetch the content, I receive the response in onNext method of the the Observable, without any need to use the Retrofit2 method onResponse:

> adapter.addAll(stackOverflowQuestions.items);

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
    StackOverflowAPI stackOverflowAPI = retrofit.create(StackOverflowAPI.class);


    //the real call to the server
    //Call<StackOverflowQuestions> call = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions("android");


    Observable<StackOverflowQuestions> observable = stackOverflowAPI.loadQuestions("android");

    observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<StackOverflowQuestions>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("IVO", "completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(StackOverflowQuestions stackOverflowQuestions) {

                    Log.d("IVO", "onNext " + stackOverflowQuestions.items.get(0).title.toString());
                    Log.d("IVO", "onNext " + stackOverflowQuestions.items.get(1).title.toString());
                    Log.d("IVO", "onNext " + stackOverflowQuestions.items.get(2).title.toString());

                    Log.d("IVO", "onNext");
              ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Question>) getListAdapter();

                    adapter.clear();
                    //setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                  //  adapter.addAll(response.body().itemsitems);
                    adapter.addAll(stackOverflowQuestions.items);

                }
            });


    return true;
}
}
```